# Почему std::multiset не работает с константами?

Tags: c++

Почему уже при создании множества, вылетает ошибка, хотя не был изменен массив?

Пример кода:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

class B {
public:
    std::array<int, 3> b;

    void constFunc() const {    // error
//    void constFunc() {          // done
        std::multiset<std::reference_wrapper<int> > ms;
        ms.insert(b.begin(), b.end());
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.constFunc();
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Как можно исправить ситуацию, оставляя прототип с константой и не создавая копию массива?

Comment: измените на `std::multiset<std::reference_wrapper<int const> >`

Comment: По большому счету, что вы хотите выиграть, "не создавая копию"? Место в памяти? так вы его проигрываете...

Comment: @Harry `int` был в примере. на самом деле там объект класса

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так как `void constFunc() const` отмечен как `const`, для него `b` имеет тип `const std::array<int, 3>`. Значит `*b.begin()` (и подобные выражения) имеет тип `const int`.

А `std::reference_wrapper<int>`  может ссылаться только на неконстантные `int`ы.

Пытаться поместить ссылку на `const int` в `std::multiset<std::reference_wrapper<int>>` - это все равно что пытаться сделать что-то вроде:

```
const int a = 1;
int &b = a; // ошибка
```

Как подсказывают в комментариях, можно использовать:

```
std::multiset<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> ms;
```

Либо, если вам на самом деле не нужны ссылки, можно сделать:

```
std::multiset<int> ms;
```

Либо можно убрать `const` с метода.